# Display a map using geotools java in a javafx application

Tags: geoserver, geotiff-tiff, geotools, javafx

i have added [geotools java](http://geotools.org) to my Netbeans IDE and now i want to display this [map](https://geo.nyu.edu/catalog/harvard-g8241-e1-1846-c3) in my javafx application.I have downloaded its geotiff from the same site and it's a zip file (176 mb)  which contains three files:

1. G8241_E1_1846_C3.j2w    ( 1 kb)
2. G8241_E1_1846_C3.jp2    ( 175788  kb)
3. G8241_E1_1846_C3.xml    (13  kb)

I have no idea how to approach that.

Answer (score 2):

That is a JPEG2000 image not a geotiff - you will need to use the [GDAL ImageIO plugin](http://docs.geotools.org/stable/userguide/library/coverage/imageio.html) to read it in.

Once you have a coverage following [the Image Tutorial](http://docs.geotools.org/latest/userguide/tutorial/raster/image.html) should show you the right route, though that's for Swing not JavaFX but the changes should be straightforward.